# Pattern Matching on scala.xml.NodeSeq

Tags: xml, scala

Given:

```
$cat build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml"   % "1.0.6"
```

and, then

```
$sbt console

def exactlyOne[A](xs: Seq[A]): Option[A] = xs match {
 case head :: Nil => Some(head)
 case _           => None
}

scala> val xml = <root><a/></root>
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <root><a/></root>

scala> xml \ "a"
res3: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<a/>)

scala> exactlyOne( res3 )
res4: Option[scala.xml.Node] = None
```

Evidently, `Seq#unapply` is not being used:

```
scala> exactlyOne( Seq(1) )
res2: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

My understanding is that `unapply` will get called, typically on the class's `companion object`.

I found `Node#unapplySeq` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/scala-xml/index.html#scala.xml.Node$@unapplySeq(n:scala.xml.Node):Some[(String,scala.xml.MetaData,Seq[scala.xml.Node])]), but I'm not sure if that's being called.

Which method is getting called on `match` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NodeSeq` is not a `List`, so trying to pattern match it as one will fail. If you wanted to match it using `unapplySeq` of some kind, you would need to do it in this way:

```
def exactlyOne[A](xs: Seq[A]): Option[A] = xs match {
  case Seq(head) => Some(head)
  case _ => None
}

scala> exactlyOne(<root>hello</root>)
res5: Option[scala.xml.Node] = Some(<root>hello</root>)

scala> exactlyOne(<root>hello</root><foo>world</foo>)
res6: Option[scala.xml.Node] = None
```

Comment: So, when calling `match`, how will `Seq#unapplySeq` be resolved - http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.Seq$@unapplySeq[A](x:CC[A]):Some[CC[A]]?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. When the compiler sees `case Seq(...)` it looks for `Seq.unapply` and `Seq.unapplySeq` (and finds the latter).

Comment: So unaply and unapplySeq are special, then, for matching? In other words, we could not use another method with match?

Comment: See http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#extractor-patterns and the following section. Yes, they are special.